# Android Studio Flutter MP3 file/ raw resource folder not reconized

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am getting a problem with flutter android studio, i simply want to add an mp3 file but when i add it in a resource folder it says file of unknown type

when i try to right click the res folder to create a raw android resource file i get the error Cannot find resource directory for module Module: 'my_new_app_android'

i have added the audioplayers in my pubspec.yaml file and seems like nothing i do will work and everything i see on the internet is just people dragging and dropping mp3 files with no issue

i have tried to update the pubspec file with different types of audio player packegdes, i have inserted a wav file instead i have renamed, i have made sure i dont use any capital letter or space, i have run flutter clean, i have restarded the system, i have put my pc in developer mode. i have tried running android studio in admin mode.

Thank you for your time, i hope you have a great day

Comment: Could you please add the code so that we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
i can certainly add the code for you although I strongly believe the code not to be an issue here and it has something to do with my IDE. i cannot create a raw file and I cannot drag and drop mp3 even if I open a brand new fresh project I cannot create a raw file in my app>src>main>res I right click and create a raw resource folder but I get the error "Cannot find resource directory for module Module: 'my_new_app_android' when i drag and drop my mp3 file into my assets file it just says file of an unknown type

Comment: Then you could open the project in the finder/explorer and add the mp3 that way.

Comment: ive spent the whole day trying to figure it out look all over the internet, done everything google and chatgpt have told me for 10+ hours litterly done ever single thing I could find on the internet even creating a new file and transferring my code. nothing will make android studio recognize a .mp3 .wav or .org file just "file of unknown type"